# How do I assign aggregate values to multiple variables on the same column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL, I have an OrderTable with columns for dates, sale prices, and product ids. I am trying to get average prices over a date interval based on product id.

For example, given the following table:

```
SaleDate   ProductId   Price
--------   ---------   -----
1/1/2020   1           1.00
1/2/2020   1           2.00
1/2/2020   2           1.00
1/2/2020   2           3.00
1/3/2020   2           2.00
1/3/2020   1           1.00
1/3/2020   3           2.00
```

I want the equivalent of the following:

```
SELECT @t1 = AVG(Price) FROM OrderTable WHERE ProductId = 1
SELECT @t2 = AVG(Price) FROM OrderTable WHERE ProductId = 2
SELECT @t3 = AVG(Price) FROM OrderTable WHERE ProductId = 3
```

I know I can group them by ProductId, like so:

```
SELECT ProductId, AVG(Price) FROM OrderTable GROUP BY ProductId
```

And get the average price for each ProductId, but how do I assign those to multiple variables?

I want to do something like this (this doesn't work):

```
SELECT @t1 = AVG(Price) WHERE ProductId = 1,
@t2 = AVG(Price) WHERE ProductId = 2,
@t3 = AVG(Price) WHERE ProductId = 3
FROM OrderTable
```

Comment: what is your expected output ? please show us in tabular form. also tag your SQL engine? like sql server, my sql etc.

Comment: "SQL" has no variables.Which DBMS product are you using? [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation to put them all in one row:

```
select @t1 = avg(case when productid = 1 then price end),
       @t2 = avg(case when productid = 2 then price end),
       @t3 = avg(case when productid = 3 then price end)
from OrderTable;
```

I assume the syntax `@t1 =` is what your database uses for assigning variables.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I thought of the case statement, but I did not realize you could place it within an aggregate function.